# How can I simulate a "touchmove" event on an html element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, dom-events

I have a script tag on a website which I am using to manipulate the page after load. Since the site is built using a host of frameworks and libraries interacting with the page using JS can be difficult. Often the easiest way to get the page to respond is by simulating a user click which is a piece of cake. However, recently I came across a problem that required a `touchmove` event to trigger a custom scroll on a div. I know simulating a `touchmove` event is possible but I have no idea how it is done.

I have tried piecing the process together from pages such as the following:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchmove

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent

I don't understand how I would indicate a speed or coordinates.

Can anyone point me to some documentation that clears this up?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the code of your attempts.

Comment: Easiest?  Use Chrome, turn on the developer frame, switch from responsive to a phone, then click and drag, it simulates touch.

Comment: Hi @wayneOS. I really didn't get very far writing code to solve this issue since I simply don't know how to do it. This is as far as I got

`let touch = document.createEvent('CustomEvent')
touch.initEvent('build', true, true)
element.dispatchEvent(touch)`

Thanks for the advice @Trevor D but this is not just for testing. I would like the events to be triggered in response to user interactions